# The realization problem for a trilinear map from the cup product

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given a closed manifold $M$ of dimension $3D$, we can construct an alternating trilinear map $\alpha(a, b, c) = \int_M a \cup b \cup c$ where $a, b, c \in H^D(M)$.

The question is the realization question: Given an arbitrary alternating trilinear map, is there a closed manifold $M$ that generates such a trilinear map?

A variant of this question is to allow $a, b, c$ to come from different levels.

Comment: I suppose $M$ should be assumed closed and orientable? Or do you have a different notion of integral/forms in mind? Either way, please edit your post to clarify this. (Also, dimension is a number: $M$ is of dimension $3D$, **not** $\mathbb{R}^{3D}$.)

Comment: Assuming that this is about closed, orientable manifolds, Poincaré duality tells you that the pairing $\mathrm{PD}\colon H^p(M) \otimes H^{n - p}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathrm{PD}(\omega \otimes \eta) = \int_M \omega \cup \eta$ is perfect for all $p$, so the case $p = D$ already forces some nicety conditions on the possible trilinear maps.

Comment: It is not clear to me what PD actually says about the trilinear form, eg on $S^2 \times S^4$ the trilinear form is $0$.

Comment: @ronno ...yes, since the cup-product on $H^2(S^2 \times S^4)$ is trivial. But observe that if $P = \{a \smile b\mid a, b \in H^D(M)\} \subseteq H^{2D}(M)$ is the sub-vector space of all products of element of $H^D(M)$, then duality gives an _injection_ $\mathrm{PD}\colon P \hookrightarrow H^D(M)^*$, so in a sense at least the question of "how degenerate can the form be" reduces to a question about the cup product.

Comment: To put it slightly differently, it might be a good idea to study the problem in terms of two bilinear maps: The cup product $\smile\colon H^D(M) \times H^D(M) \to H^{2D}(M)$ and the duality pairing $\mathrm{PD}\colon H^{2D}(M) \times H^D(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ and then piece things together, and maybe it would be good for tclin to show some work in that direction.

Comment: I still don't see how that constrains the form. It is true that PD restricts the rank of the cup product $H^D \otimes H^D \to H^{2D}$ given $\alpha$, but this rank could very well be $0$.

Comment: @tclin, $\alpha$ is only alternating if $D$ is odd, otherwise it should be symmetric.

Comment: Maybe more precisely, a map $V^{\otimes 3} \to \mathbf{R}$ is equivalent to a map $V \otimes V \to V^*$, and if $\alpha$ is of the described form then this is exactly the composition $H^D \otimes H^D \xrightarrow{\smile} H^{2D} \xrightarrow[\approx]{\text{PD}} (H^D)^*$.